# Is the square of the spin exchange operator 1?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, spinors

The Dirac [spin exchange operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices#Relation_with_the_permutation_operator) is defined as,

\begin{equation}
P_\sigma = \frac{1}{2} (1 + \vec{\sigma}_1 \cdot \vec{\sigma}_2)
\end{equation}

Is $P_\sigma ^2 = 1$ ?

I think it should be, because applying the exchange operator twice should result in an identity, but I'm not sure how to prove it mathematically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. It can be seen easily by using a very utilized change in QM. You can see that $$ \vec{\sigma}_1 \vec{\sigma}_2 = \frac{1}{2} ( (\vec{\sigma}_1+\vec{\sigma}_2)^2 - \vec{\sigma}_1^2 -\vec{\sigma}_2^2   )$$

N.B. here we use the fact that $\vec{\sigma}_1 \vec{\sigma}_2 = \vec{\sigma}_2 \vec{\sigma}_1$ since they operate on different Hilbert spaces.

Now, from Pauli matrices algebra $\vec{\sigma}^2 = 3 $ therefore
$$ \vec{\sigma}_1 \vec{\sigma}_2 = -3 +\frac{1}{2}  (\vec{\sigma}_1 +\vec{\sigma}_2)^2 = -3 +2  (\vec{S}_1+\vec{S}_2)^2 $$

since $\vec{S} = \frac{1}{2} \vec{\sigma}$.

So the spin-exchange can be written as
$$
\frac{1}{2}(1+ \vec{\sigma}_1 \vec{\sigma}_2 ) = -1 + (\vec{S}_1 + \vec{S}_2)^2
$$
You should know from spin addition algebra that there are a [singlet state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singlet_state) and three [triplet states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triplet_state) that are eigenstates of $(\vec{S}_1 + \vec{S}_2)^2 $ with eigenvalues 0 for the singlet and 2 for the triplets, therefore there are four linear independent states for which the this operator has a diagonalan representation as:
$(\vec{S}_1 + \vec{S}_2)^2  = diag(0,2,2,2)$

and therefore, on the same basis, the spin exchange operator have diagonal representation as:

$$
\frac{1}{2}(1+ \vec{\sigma}_1 \vec{\sigma}_2 ) = diag(-1,1,1,1 )
$$

The square of this matrix is clearly the identity as you wanted to prove.

Answer (score 0):

In wikipedia they say that each eigenvalues are + 1,-1. So I guess you are right. Also you can verify it if you analyze the spin vector $\vec{\sigma}$=($\sigma_x$,$\sigma_y$,$\sigma_z$)